# When should you use "then" and when "than"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, adverbs, conjunctions, comparisons

As far as I know, *then* is used in a conjunction and in time-related sentences; *than* in all other cases. I believe that these are correct:

- Because I'm older than she, I should be the first chosen;
- I loved her and then she died;
- If it rains [then] it pours;
- I've had more then enough;
- Would you rather be a mouse then a rat?
- Who, other than you, likes the color red?

Or not? Can someone help me out clearing the mud? I think I'm 90% there, but I like to finally understand it completely. If you have other uses of then/than that I missed, please add yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Because I'm older than she, I should be the first chosen.

> I loved her and then she died.

> If it rains, then it pours.

> I've had more than enough.

> Would you rather be a mouse than a rat?

> Who, other than you, likes the color red?

When there is a comparison, you use *than*; *then* means:

> 1. at that time; at the time in question: *I was living in Cairo then* | [after preposition] *Phoebe by then was exhausted* | [as adjective] *a hotel where the then prime minister, Margaret Thatcher, was staying*.
> 2. after that; next; afterward: *she won the first and then the second game*.
>
>    - also; in addition: *I'm paid a generous salary, and then there's the money I've made at the races*.
> 3. in that case; therefore: *if you do what I tell you, then there's nothing to worry about* | *well, that's okay then*.
>
>    - used at the end of a sentence to emphasize an inference being drawn: *so you're still here, then*.
>    - used to finish off a conversation: *see you in an hour, then*.

(See also the definition of [*then*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/then) given in the *Oxford Living Dictionaries*.)

Comment: So, you are saying *than* is only used with comparisons, so all others should be *then*? Or do I oversimplify? And in the *if..then* case, *then* means "in that case", right?

Comment: @Abel: Yes. Actually, "than" is used also in expressions introducing an exception or contrast (he claims not to own anything other than his home), or indicating one thing happening immediately after another (scarcely was the work completed than it was abandoned).

Comment: Interesting, esp. your last example, because it seems to indicate time and thus, should be written with *then*. But this then, is an exception or special case, or the meaning is just different than I'd imagined (as a non-native English speaker)?

Comment: @Abel: It's a special case, which is an exception of the normal meaning of the word. `:-)` The cases I reported in the comment are exceptions; if you remember what I reported in the answer, you should use the right word more easily.

Comment: "Scarcely was the work complete than it was abandoned," is not a correct sentence. The way 'than' is used in that sentence is "No sooner was the work complete than it was abandoned." In this sentence 'than' is used because it's a comparison. 'Than' doesn't have any special meaning for things happening immediately after other things.

Comment: All of these constructions (the grammatical ones, anyway) are comparative (_sooner, other, older, more, rather_). _Than_ can only be used in a comparative construction. No comparative, no _than_.

Answer (score 4):

Two corrections:

- I’ve had more than enough.
- Would you rather be a mouse than a rat?

Both “rather . . . than . . .” and “more than” are fixed expressions.

Comment: *are fixed expressions* >> if I may: looking at @kiamlaluno's answer, I'd say that they are comparisons ;)

Comment: @Abel: fair to say.

Comment: *More than* and *rather than* are still comparisons.  They are idioms as well, but still comparative.  The one that may give rise to some confusion is *rather than*, in which case *rather* is the comparative of an archaic adverb *rathe* 'soon, quickly'.  Thus 'I would rather have X than Y' is literally identical to 'I would sooner have X than Y', albeit that they are often used in different senses.

Answer (score 0):

*Then* is time related, like you said. It divides two (or more) occurrences. Example below.

> Jack went to the shop, **then** he went to his grandmother.

*Than* is a word we use when comparing something. If something is *more* or *less* than something else. Examples below.

> Jack is stronger **than** Cole.

.

> Cole is weaker **than** Jack.

Also, *then* is always preceded by a comma or an "and" (unless you're speaking about the word itself). *Than* is never preceded by a comma.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: I don't think there's always a comma before *then*, see the first answer for examples.

Comment: True, I forgot to say it's either a comma or an "and".

Comment: *that decision was taken by the then president*, shows up as first example in Google. Or *just then she walked in*, or *back then, he was my neighbour*, or *apart from then, what about now* . The beauty with language is that there are often more exceptions than rules.

Comment: In the first example, "then" is used as an adjective to describe the president as not now, but back "then".  Another version is "then-currently". The others a kind of phrasal, but I see what you mean, and I should've elaborated on possible exceptions.